# ORA-12571 TNS packet writer failure

Tags: asp.net, oracle, tns

What is the reason behind this error and how could I solve this problem?? If possible please provide me good explanations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is know as an antivirus issue (Panda or MacAfee). Look [here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_12571_tns_packet_writer_failure.htm)

Answer (score 0):

This error can occur that has an alias name greater than 25 characters in the file tnsnames.ora. Try decreasing the size of the alias to resolve this problem.

Other topic solution

*If the following error occurs during while committing data to the database, it indicates a network error during data transmission and may be attributed to using an older version of the Oracle client which does not match the version of the Oracle database. Check the version of the Oracle database as well as the version of Oracle client on the local machine. Consistent version between the Oracle database and Oracle client may help resolve this error.*